# How to know intensity value of points in images

Tags: python, image, opencv, imagej

I'd like to know intensities of specific coordinates in images.

For example, when I see an image, if I think "I want to know the intensity of this specific point!", how can I get the intensity?

I can use opencv and imageJ, but if you know any other tools to solve this, I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use opencv in python see http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('some.jpg')

px = img[1,1]
print px
```

returns blue, green, red intensities of pixel 1,1:

```
[55 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I were able to solve the question using imagej's analyze's measure!
Thank you very much!!